# How to pass data in Grafana Variables and link it with dashboard API's

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable, grafana-dashboard

So I have a grafana variable .And from the API's it returns alist of ID's.

[image]

So I have this api that I have linked with a dashboard panel and it requires an id to return a value based on an mrd id. eg. /mrd-stats/?mrdid=23982372489198 .

[image]

So I don't want to display the ids on the dropdown, instead I want to display the names of the mrd which will be meaningful instead of displaying my ids to the user. Is there a way that I can display the Mrd names on the dropdown and link it somehow with the api intergrated on the dashboard . Note the apis integrated on the dashboard requires only mrd id.

Comment: Did you found the way for your problem?

Comment: Yes. I created two variables, one which returns all the ids and the other which returns the names. I had set the variable that return the ids to hidden since I don't want the end users to see a list of ids, only the names should be displayed which are meaningful to the end user.

Next step is , I linked the two variables , then based on the name , I am filtering out the id which match the name selected on the variable. Then based on the name selected it will append the id to "/mrd-stats/?mrdid=$MRD_ID"